# Url rewriting: Redirect one page to another

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-7.5

I want to create a rule to redirect query to a page (which doesn't exist) to another

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/en/page.asp?id=2&...
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/en-US/newpage.asp?id=2&...
```

I use this rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="page\.asp\?(.+)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="newpage.asp?{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

But this doesn't work... I got a 404 error...

What is my mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. URL Rewrite's Rewrite action is only for rewriting the page URL that
   gets displayed on the browser but it expects the original page to
   exist on the server. For your case, you need a Redirect action.
2. The regex needs to be changed to reflect "en-US" in the final URL.

Try this code instead:

```
<rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="en/page\.asp\?(.+)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="en-US/newpage.asp?{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

The permanent redirect helps makes your website SEO (Search Engine Optimized) preventing search engine bots to index the old URL (and hence not splitting page ranks between the 2 URLs).

Comment: Ok, redirect is better and I didn't know the original page should exist... but it make sense after reflexion ;). Your exemple doesn't work. I'll update my question to be more precise

Comment: Ah you have en-US in the new URL which is not taken care by your regex. Hence you are getting the 404. Edited the code in my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Can you extract the URL from the 404 page to see if the final URL is what it needed to be? Either this URL will be in the page response or just do a View Source to get the URL. Also (I know this sounds basic) check if you are able to browse properly to "http://www.example.com/en-US/newpage.asp?id=2&..." with no errors.